# undervolting information for Solaris

Tags: solaris, open-source, x86

Looking for **[undervolting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_voltage_scaling)** procedures (or tools) for Solaris/Opensolaris **x86**?

#### Info:

- BIOS config: LENOVO 68ET37WW
- CPU Into: Intel Core 2 Duo T5250

Comment: Good question, but isn't that about BIOS (which is OS indeendent :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [Intel PowerTOP](http://www.opensolaris.org/os/project/tesla/Work/Powertop/) on Solaris to watch which software makes your computer to consume more energy.

Also you can upgrade your servers to Solaris 10 5/09 release which supports processor clock throttling.

For more information visit [OpenSolaris Power Management Community](http://opensolaris.org/os/community/pm/) and your BIOS (if it's PC).

Comment: @Bolotov: Thanks. As far as I am aware, the default BIOS firmware does not permit CPU undervolting.